# Visual studio extension setting the git branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, git-branch, vsix

I am writing an extension (VSIX) in VS and one feature is to change the GIT branch. GIT is integrated in VS (2019) and also the method to change a branch should be present but I cannot find any documentation: is there a method to change the GIT-Branch

Thanks

Comment: You can explore the [git-lens](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens) repo, to be specific perhaps [this code](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/34792752d9621c4223757057c8409b453cdea355/src/git/git.ts). Did you checkout the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider) which refers to [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/git/src/repository.ts).

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick The question was about VisualStudio and your answer is about VisualStudioCode...

Comment: VS use an internal version of git to run the commands. You could try to get the path to the exe and run the git command to checkout a branch

Comment: Oops. My bad. @Philippe Thanks alot for pointing that out.

Comment: I'd like to use the same method from VS without any external extension.I thought it were possible but, if not, I will use the external git command